# How to show only US country in cart page estimate shipping & tax dropdown and admin orders side display all countries

Tags: magento2, cart, magento2.4.2, shipping-estimate

How to show US country only in magento2 cart page estimate shipping & tax dropdown and admin orders sideshow all countries

How to restrict all countries except US country in magento2 cart page estimate shipping & tax.

Answer (score 0):

Check this (maybe it helps): try changing the configuration from ***Stores -> Configuration -> General -> General -> Country Options -> Allow Countries*** - uncheck 'Use system value' and select only the countries you want to allow the estimation and the shipping (yes, this will restrict the country options from the checkout forms as well). Save the configuration and flush the caches.

Comment: I need all countries list for admin side orders and frontend cart page estimate shipping & tax dropdown I need only US country

Comment: wouldn't work if you would leave the above mentioned configuration with all countries on the admin default store and just the frontend store set with the US value only?